# How to use this power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I've needed to use a second power supply and been given this one by a friend, and I don't really understand how to use it fully. I also have a couple basic questions on use.

[image]

It has two screens, and I only understand the right half, which is the output current and voltage. Can anyone explain the left half? 
Secondly, with the configuration i've connected it, measuring with a multimeter across + and Com shows 4.089V compared to + and - which shows 4.12V, why is this?
Thirdly when doing standard things like supplying a voltage to a circuit is it better do connect + to Com or -?

Thanks

Comment: [Digimess BP3002 Manual (not incredibly helpful)](http://www.digimessinstruments.co.uk/manuals/english/mbp3002engandger.pdf), the voltage difference can be explained by either an inaccurate meter in the supply itself, or your voltage meter not being calibrated.

Comment: Am guessing that with the **volt/amp** push-button **out** (as shown), left display shows the voltage of the left supply (-) while the right display shows the voltage of the right supply (+). With the push-button pushed **in**, both displays show current...with nothing connected, they would both read zero current, no matter where you adjust any knob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a dual supply.

The left side controls the negative voltage, the right the positive.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvM4oc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When you measure from the + to the - you need to add the values shown in the two displays.

If you want to hook it up to something that needs a single supply, just use the right side and connect your thing to + and common.

BTW: With the Volts/Current button pushed in the meters will show the current being drawn by each supply instead of the voltage at the outputs.

Your difference between the displayed value and your multimeter value will be due to the calibration differences in each. In reality, neither is probably right.

Here is the PSU [manual](http://www.digimessinstruments.co.uk/manuals/english/mbp3002engandger.pdf) thanks to [Ron Beyer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/135757/ron-beyer).

Answer (score 0):

The power supply that I see in the picture is a dual power supply with a positive output voltage on RHS and negative output voltage on LHS (-30—0—30)

The two displays here show value of the voltage in the corresponding channel i.e. LHS display for left voltage output and RHS display for right voltage output. To check for current output (ampere reading) you need to toggle the pushbutton with volt and amp writing, provide on your PSU. That will show you corresponding amp value in respective channel.

Now that you have asked about the reading you had measured on your multimeter. Your current display setting is on voltage mode, so your display is showing the voltage reading in respective channel. 
When you measured voltage between com and + it showed 4.089V which your PSU had rounded off to 4.1V as shown on your display on RHS. 
When you measured voltage between - and + it showed 4.12V which is actually the addition of your RHS and LHS reading. If you subtract your multimeter reading (4.12V-4.089V=0.031V). If you see, 0.031V is the value across 'com' and '-' terminals if measured with multimeter. However, your PSU has rounded off to 0.1V as shown on LHS display.

The values shown on multimeter and display has got nothing to do with calibration and just a matter of accuracy of you instrument and that's because of the value it reads upto that single decimal place and your multimeter reads upto three decimal places.